# Something like array_search_all - replace all instances of a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Given these arrays:

```
// an array of values
$target = [5, 10, 15, 5, 25];

// an array of objects, direct from database
// all "original" values in this array are unique (no duplicates)
$replacements = [{original: 5, replacement: 7}, {original: 15, replacement: 155}, ..etc...];
```

What is the most efficient / performant way to replace all instances of the original value in `$target` with the replacement value in the `$replacement` array?  Desired result:

```
// note that BOTH instances of the value 5 were replaced...
$result = [7, 10, 155, 7, 25];
```

This is what I have now, but doesn't feel optimal:

```
foreach ( $replacements AS $sub ) {
    // I hate assignments within conditions, but DO want performance
    while ( FALSE !== ($index = array_search( $sub->original, $target ) ) ) {
        $target[ $index ] = $sub->replacement;
    }
}
```

NOTE: PHP version is 5.6

**Relevant Notes:**
1. The `$target` array may contain anywhere from 5 to 30 values, but typically would be 10-15 values.
2. The `$target` array may contain duplicate values.
3. The `$replacements` array may contain from 1 to 8 objects, but typically would be 2 or 3 objects.
4. There are no concerns over `$replacements` containing duplicate `original` values.
5. There are no concerns over `$replacement` containing "cascading" values.  (That is, no concern that one object replaces the value 5 with the value 7, and then another object replacing the value 7 with another value).

The reason that performance is a concern is that this might get called  couple thousand times with different `$target` and `$replacement` values.

Comment: Are you doing this once, or many times over?

Comment: If you use PHP 7 you can just do: `$result = str_replace(array_column($replacements, "original"), array_column($replacements, "replacement"), $target);`

Comment: @Rizier123 - Wow.  No idea str_replace worked on arrays.  Why does that solution require PHP 7?  I'm on 5.6...

Comment: what is your PHP version?

Comment: Also, could be there overlapping objects like `{original: 5, replacement: 7}, {original: 5, replacement: 15}` ?

Comment: in [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) docs, they say in changelog since 7 "Added the ability for the input parameter to be an array of objects." which your `$relacements` array is I think

Comment: the problem of using `str_replace` is that a pattern might match a wider pattern that's declared later. E.g., in your example: 5 and 15. As seen [here](https://repl.it/FrnX/0), this approach might have some problems.

Comment: To the downvoter: Why? This is a clear question, which shows research effort, and as far as I can tell, is on topic and well constructed.  Are you grumpy today?

Answer (score 1):

There's some caveat: If `5` will be replaced with `7` and there could be an object like `{original: 7, replacement: 15}` - and it will replace the previously replaced value, in "very" circular traversal. 
With this `{original: 5, replacement: 7}, {original: 7, replacement: 25}` - when you expect `5` to become `7` - it will eventually become `25`. This could be confusing and unexpected loop.

The following should be one of the most optimal solutions(especially if the `$replacements` would have a large number of items):
Let's say we have the following `replacement` set:

```
[{"original": 5, "replacement": 7}, {"original": 15, "replacement": 155},{"original": 25, "replacement": 27},{"original": 10, "replacement": 17},{"original": 15, "replacement": 255},{"original": 23, "replacement": 27},{"original": 17, "replacement": 17}]
```

---

Use additional array(`$replaced_keys`) for accumulating keys which have been processed.

```
$target = [5, 10, 15, 5, 25];

$target_count = count($target);
$replaced_keys = [];

foreach ($replacements as $sub) {
    while (false !== ($index = array_search($sub->original, $target)) 
            && !in_array($index, $replaced_keys)) {

        $target[$index] = $sub->replacement;
        $replaced_keys[] = $index;
    }

    // avoiding circular repalcements and redundant iterations at one go
    if (count($replaced_keys) == $target_count) break;
}

print_r($target);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 155
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 27
)
```

Comment: as for `!== false`, of course, just missed that. As for your 2nd moment, why it shouldn't ? You said: *No, all original values in $replacements will be unique.*

Comment: @cale_b, ok. let me think a minute

Comment: For a single `$replacement` object, say `{original: 5, replacement: 7}`, ALL instances of 5 should be replaced with 7.  I don't see how your array_search will find / replace more than the first instance.

Comment: I have figured out that there's another one caveat: If `5` will be replaced by `7` and there could be an object like `{original: 7, replacement: 15}` - and it will replace the previously replaced value, "very" circular traversal. `{original: 5, replacement: 7}, {original: 7, replacement: 25}` - when you expect `5` to become `7` - it will eventually become `25`. This could be confusing and unexpected loop

Answer (score 1):

Tentatively:

```
foreach ($target as &$item) {
    foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
        if ($item == $replacement->original) {
            $item = $replacement->replacement;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming **$target** generally has less elements than **$replacements**. The **break** stops searching *all* replacements every time, since the originals are unique. Question is, is foreach slower than array_search.

It may even be faster to copy your replacements into an array proper first, if it's fairly large, and use that instead to look up the value directly (and not have the inner foreach):

```
$replace_array = array();
foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
    $replace_array[$replacement->original] = $replacement->$replacement;
}
```

**EDIT**

Thinking about it some more. Since you have repeat values in **$target**, there may be some merit in not searching the replacements twice:

```
asort($target);
$previous_item = false;
$previous_replace = false;
foreach ($target as &$item) {
    if ($item==$previous_item && $previous_replace!==false) {
        $item = $previous_replace;
    } else {
        $previous_replace = false;
        foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
            if ($item == $replacement->original) {
                $previous_replace = $replacement->replacement;
                $previous_item = $item;
                $item = $previous_replace;
                break;
            }
        }           
    }
}
ksort($target);
```